# Create a sophisticated livelock

Tags: popularity-contest, concurrency

<sub>The point of the puzzle is to learn about [livelocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livelock):</sub>

Create a multi-threaded (or a multi-process) program, whose threads (processes) indefinitely try to wait for each other and never finish. Unlike a deadlock situation, the state of threads (processes) in a livelock constantly change as they try to resolve the situation, but never succeeding.

The task isn't to create a shortest or a simplest solution. Try to create a solution that resembles a real situation, something that looks like a genuine piece of code, but with some kind of an error that creates the livelock.

This is a popularity contest. The most up-voted answer in ~10 days wins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Ruby

Based on the [Dining Philosophers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) tale - 4 philosophers:

> Five silent philosophers sit at a table around a bowl of spaghetti. A
>   fork is placed between each pair of adjacent philosophers. (An
>   alternative problem formulation uses rice and chopsticks instead of
>   spaghetti and forks.)
>
> Each philosopher must alternately think and eat. However, a
>   philosopher can only eat spaghetti when he has both left and right
>   forks. Each fork can be held by only one philosopher and so a
>   philosopher can use the fork only if it's not being used by another
>   philosopher. After he finishes eating, he needs to put down both forks
>   so they become available to others. A philosopher can grab the fork on
>   his right or the one on his left as they become available, but can't
>   start eating before getting both of them.

```ruby
class Fork

  attr_reader :owner
  def initialize
   @mutex = Mutex.new
  end

  def pickup(new_owner)
    @mutex.synchronize do
      if @owner.nil?
        @owner = new_owner
    return true
      end
      return false
    end
  end

  def release(owner)
     @mutex.synchronize do
      if @owner == owner
        @owner = nil
    return true
      end
      return false
    end
  end
end

class Philosopher

  attr_reader :name, :hungry
  attr_accessor :left_fork, :right_fork

  def initialize(name, left_fork, right_fork)
    @name = name
    @hungry = true
    @left_fork = left_fork
    @right_fork = right_fork
  end

  def eat
    while hungry
      got_left = left_fork.pickup(self)
      think
      got_right = right_fork.pickup(self)
      if got_left && got_right
        @hungry = false
    puts "#{name} has eaten!"
      end
      right_fork.release(self) 
      think 
      left_fork.release(self)
    end
    puts "#{name} ended"
  end

  def think
    puts "#{name} thinks..."
    sleep 1
  end
end

fork = nil
philosophers = %w(aristotle plato confucius descartes).map { |p| Philosopher.new(p, fork, fork = Fork.new) }
philosophers[0].left_fork = fork

threads = philosophers.map do |p|
  puts p.left_fork.pickup(p)
  Thread.new {
    p.eat
  }
end

threads.map(&:join)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Game Maker Language

Script `add`:

```
subtract=argument0
add(not(subtract))
```